# WiX: Set registry key if it does not exist and prevent it from being deleted with a major upgrade

Tags: wix, windows-installer, registry

My goal is to set a registry key value on a fresh install or upgrade if it does not already exist. To that end I defined a property and from a registry search and added a condition to my component:

```
    <Property Id="AN_ID_HERE">
        <RegistrySearch Id="anIdHere"
                      Root="HKCU"
                      Key="Path\To\Key"
                      Name="Value"
                      Type="raw"/>
    </Property>

    <Fragment>
        <Component Id="MyComponentId" Guid="xxx">
            <Condition>
                <![CDATA[(NOT AN_ID_HERE)]]>
            </Condition>
            <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Path\To\Key">
                <RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="Value" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
            </RegistryKey>
        </Component>
    </Fragment>
```

This caused the key to be removed and not replaced with major upgrades, presumably because `AN_ID_HERE` has some value when it is evaluated (before the registry key is removed). I also tried adding `NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE` to the condition to try to prevent the key from being removed, but this did not have any effect.

I attempted a solution I saw referred to as the "remember property pattern": http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern/. My issue with this method was that `RegistrySearch` will read a REG_DWORD with value 1 as "#1", so the new registry value will be set as a REG_SZ, which will not work for my purposes.

Comment: If this registry value is present in the major upgrade package then it should not be removed. Especially if the component ID is the same as in the previous version. BTW what is the reason for the condition?

Comment: yes what are you trying to do with that registry entry/condition?